# Selecting min(value) and max(value) from a column and returning it in a single row Using Listagg in Oracle

Tags: max, aggregate, oracle12c, min, listagg

I have a table like below

```
gen_id pos_id Language Value
1221    1234    EN      1.0 m
1221    1234    EN      2.0 m
1221    1234    EN      3.0 m
1221    1234    EN      4.9 m
```

I wanted to select the value as : "1.0 m - 4.9 m".

Select the min(value) and max(value) separated by a string "-".

I tried the below listagg but it throws the error
"ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"".

```
Select  LISTAGG (min(value) || '-' || max(value))   
             WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY pos_id)
             OVER (PARTITION BY geng_id,pos_id,language)
From TSS_Gen where geng_id = 1221 and Pos_id = 1234;
```

Comment: What error do you get? And please post your complete query ...

Comment: If you are using string comparison then `100.0 m` is less than `2 m` as, for the first characters `1` is less than `2`. Do **NOT** store numeric values as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, do **NOT** store numbers as string with units; store them as numbers.

---

Assuming numeric values then you do not need to use `LISTAGG` (or an analytic function) and can simply aggregate and use string concatenation:

```sql
SELECT min(value) || ' m - ' || max(value) || ' m'
FROM   TSS_Gen
WHERE  geng_id = 1221
AND    Pos_id = 1234;
```

If you are storing units then assuming that they are all metres then:

```
SELECT min(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(value, 1, LENGTH(value) - 2))) || ' m'
       || ' - '
       || max(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(value, 1, LENGTH(value) - 2))) || ' m'
FROM   TSS_Gen
WHERE  geng_id = 1221
AND    Pos_id = 1234;
```